# Php pages dependent on query string but what if there's no parameter?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, get

I am creating pages that are dependent on a query in the url (eg europe.php?country=france). I am aware that it will be useful to re-write theses  as europe.php/france with htaccess for SEO etc but what if that page is accessed without the query string?

I am using php to $_GET the query, so if I access the page without the query I get 'var=;' ie, it is empty (and retrieves an error). I'm trying to use an if statement to check if the $_GET retrieves nothing but am unsure if this is the right thing to do.

So: how do I check for an un-retrieved var so I can set a default?
Or: am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way, definitely. For sure you want to move away from URLs formatted that way, as a start, just in case this website isn't always php-based. Also, you need to include some of your source code to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Thanks, Jordan. I'm going to try and mimimise the use of query-based urls, though will need to keep some. I have started to use the html5 sessionStorage functionality, but certainly there are variables that need to remain server-side. Code-wise I will endevour to use examples in my questions from now on. Any advice on dynamic page building is gratefully accepted, gavin.

Comment: I would use either mod_rewrite or some other function to change your urls for you. So instead of `europe.php?country=france` you have `europe/france`.

Comment: Yes, that is my intention (though I'm not sure my apache server has to have it enabled). Do you know if this re-write is necessary for SE indexing or can urls with query strings be indexed?

Comment: URLs with query strings can be indexed. But with the technology easily available now, there's no reason to use query strings except for the result of a search form. Otherwise, it's much better to have normal URLs in order to keep URLs permanent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the index into `$_GET`, use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset):

```
$country = 'default';
if( isset( $_GET['country'])) {
    $country = $_GET['country'];
}
```

This will only test if the `country` parameter was passed, but it could have been set to an empty string. If this is invalid input, you can combine the check using [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty):

```
$country = 'default';
if( isset( $_GET['country']) && !empty( $_GET['country'])) {
    $country = $_GET['country'];
}
```

You can condense this into one line and save the result to a variable `$country` using the [ternary operator](http://us.php.net/ternary), like so:

```
$country = (isset( $_GET['country']) && !empty( $_GET['country'])) ? $_GET['country'] : 'default';
```

Finally, you can check if you got absolutely no `$_GET` parameters by calling [`count()`](http://php.net/count) on `$_GET`:

```
if( count( $_GET) == 0) {
    die( "No parameters - Invalid input!");
}
```

Comment: `if( count( $_GET) == 0)` has the same result as `if (!$_GET)` - with the difference of having the overhead of *actually counting* the number of elements in the array. so only use `count()` to identify the number of items in an array, never use it to test if in array is empty or not.

Comment: @rodneyrehm - Not quite, as internally, PHP keeps a count of the number of elements in an array at all times. So, it is a `O(1)` lookup time, and the performance difference is negligible. Not to mention that `if( count( $_GET) == 0)` is much more readable than `if (!$_GET)`.

Comment: also `isset($foo) && !empty($foo)` is false for `$foo == "0"`

Comment: @rodneyrehm And what country do you know of that is named `"0"`? Seems like proper functionality to me.

Comment: Obviously there is no country called "0". My point is that it's a common pitfall and should be noted.

Comment: Thanks guys - I have used the first instance of your answer here and it works fine. If I encounter any problems, I can always refer back here as there is plenty of information. :>

Answer (score 1):

try using something like this:

```
$var = ( isset($_GET['var']) ? $_GET['var'] : 'default value' )
```

Answer (score 1):

since isset() really tests for "NOT NULL", you should use [empty()](http://php.net/empty) to test if an empty string was given:

```
if (empty($_GET['country'])) {
  $_GET['country'] = "default";
}
```

that is, unless you expect `0` to be a valid input, in that case, you'd have to check with isset and make sure the string has at least one character:

```
if (!isset($_GET['country']) || !strlen($_GET['country'])) {
    $_GET['country'] = "default";
}
```

which can be optimized into

```
if (!isset($_GET['country']) || !isset($_GET['country'][0])) {
    $_GET['country'] = "default";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't using both at the same time be the best solution?

Comment: isset() is sort of a sub-set of empty(). so running isset() and empty() is partially doing the same work twice for no reason.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this out and will get back to you

Comment: In this instance I am using $long = $_GET[long]; (which is a numeric variable). So in your code "if (empty($_GET[long])) {
  $_GET[long] = 100;" where do I set the var $long please? 
}

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
if(isset($_GET['your_variable'])) { 
    $variable = $_GET['your_variable']; 
} else { 
    $variable = "not set"; 
}
```

That will set the variable if it is set in your URL - or it can set your variable to some other value if it is not set in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Running a check at the start of the page to see if var is set is fine to do. If it's empty, you can redirect using something like:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); 
header('Location:YOUR PAGE NOT FOUND PAGE');
    exit();
```

On a side note, if you're using data from $_GET, you need to make sure that this data is validated & cleaned to prevent against all sorts of security intrusions, such as XSS and, if you use a database, MYSQL injection. Running a test at the start of the page to check if it's empty can be just the start - you can also make sure that the data is something you'd expect (say, check it's alphanumeric). After, with  $_GET data, anyone could fill the URL bar with whatever they like and potentially damage your website.

Hope this has helped!

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this from a security perspective. Good to hear feedback. Its preferable for me to set the var if its empty, rather than re-direct.

Comment: So would you recommend pages being query dependent? I'm concerned about SE indexing, hence the htaccess point, but it seems they are breakable. Is there any alternative for creating dynamic pages?

Comment: It hopefully won't be breakable if the data is sanitised. i.e. Not printing any $_GET the page, but rather saving this data as a variable which is then cleaned. Alternatively, you could pass navigation along in $_POST & $_SESSION but this can get clunky. Another way to my knowledge (there may be more) would be to have dozens of small files which you physically define your vars in (say, $country = 'france') which is placed in the folder where website.com/france/ would access. Then you can just include() a template which dynamically populates the page from the DB. Hope that helps a little bit!